# Allow close votes to counter re-open votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Some times, you see a (recently) closed question that has gotten a couple of re-open votes, like this:

[image]

If you agree with the closure reason, there isn't anything you can do in cases like these. This can (imo) be a little frustrating, considering the fact questions like these sometimes only needs 1 more re-open vote to be opened again.

You could leave a tab open, waiting for someone to re-open the question, but that could take minutes, hours, days, or may not ever happen at all.

---

So, for my question:
Would it be an idea to allow users to "close-vote" on closed questions, to counteract re-open votes?

This could work just like edit review votes, where a total of 3 "accept" votes are required, after subtracting "rejection" votes (Or vice versa, -3).

These could be enabled only after a question's gotten a re-open vote, so the total votes would never go into the negatives.

---

I've found questions like these requesting "keep open" votes to counteract close votes, but no feature requests for the reverse scenario, so I figured I'd get some input from the community.

---

I just checked back on the question that inspired this suggestion, apparently 2 of the 4 re-open votes vanished. Has this feature silently been implemented? Or did 2 users vanish? Seems questionable, considering the rep you need to cast re-open votes...

Comment: +1 because I just screwed up due to the lack of this ;)

Comment: How often does this happen? If you want to get stuff closed as soon as it gets re-opened you can always seek help in a chatroom. Shouldn't we be careful with our *this should stay closed* if a couple of other members think the question deserves a chance?

Comment: I come across cases like these multiple times per week. The problem is that 20 people may think this question needs to stay closed, but can't do anything if only 5 people (including the often prejudiced OP) think the question can be re-opened. People don't usually stick around to wait for a question to be re-opened.

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately I think it could lead to the opposite case where "if there is at least 1 active close vote use a reopen vote to offset it" , which would probably get abused.

Comment: @MadScientist: that is, however, the exact opposite scenario.

Comment: Oh that *one* again - okay - I've deleted the comments as probably not relevant to the actual Q - was curious

Comment: @JonClements: Yea, some times, a "certain type" of question can inspire the greatest ideas :P

Comment: I'm seeing a couple of downvotes, so I'm curious what reason there would be not to implement something like this? Maybe my suggestion can be improved...

Comment: This is an excellent idea. What I've done in the past is I'd wait for it to re-open to close vote it again. It would be immensely useful to be able to do this. The same goes for delete votes.

Comment: This sounds like the exact opposite of [Directly vote not to close](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298520). Asked a few days ago, that one was not received nearly as well.  What explains the difference in reception?

Comment: @davidism Probably because we want to close posts and keep them closed :). In that question, it's about countering close votes, which can be done by the author of the OP. In this one, it's about countering reopen votes, which no one can do.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you can't counter close votes while they're happening any more than you can counter reopen votes while they're happening.  (Although you can retract close votes, so it's not exactly 1:1.)

Comment: You can counter further close votes, can't you? For instance, if there is a vote for a duplicate, the OP can update their question to say why it's not a duplicate, preventing (or at least minimizing the chance for) further duplicate votes...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sure, you just as easily comment saying "don't reopen this, it really is <a duplicate, off topic, etc.> for <this reason>", just like you can comment saying "reopen this for <this reason>".  Both close and reopen go into a review queue either way.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but editing merely increases the chance that people find the question good enough to stay open, it doesn't remove the current votes.

Comment: @davidism, I was just venturing a guess as to why that previous question was received poorly compared to this one. I guess I don't feel very strongly about either one. You may want to add your comments as an answer to provide an avenue for further comments.

Comment: I'm against this as there is often a flood of close votes where I believe it is people jumping on the bandwagon. I have often found myself trying to reopen a question that I needed an answer to (i.e. it was a real world issue) where most of the close votes came from people with no skills in the actual technology used (no skills on their profile, no contribution to the tags etc... e.g. C++ developers closing BlackBerry questions)

Comment: @davidism [Here's another opposite request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252010/allow-keep-open-voting-outside-review-queue#comment153498_252010), partly around pre-emptive "reopen" votes, that does seem to have been received better by the community.

Comment: FWIW it's a relatively recent feature that [reopen and close votes expire in 14 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453/165773). With expiration logic simplified like this I for one would prefer to bookmark the question (if I feel strongly enough about it) and revisit in 14 days to check if something needs to be done

Comment: @gnat: that's good to know, thanks!