# Do fast close habits comply with the Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, code-of-conduct

In the code of conduct I read:

> If you're here to help others, be patient, and welcoming

As I understand it, it does not just apply to what we write but also to what we *do*: namely voting to close a question or downvoting is not welcoming for newbies.

Of course there are still outright bad questions where the user didn't took care or not sincere. But there is also a grey zone where you can understand the question, but it's still somewhat lacking. I understand the Code of Conduct as that I should rather help improve the question instead of downvoting or voting to close if it's from a newbie (I wouldn't be so nice for an experienced Stack Overflow user).

The trouble is that naysayers are ruling: anybody more strict than I will vote to close, and I have no way to vote for keeping it open or balancing a close vote. Currently it has to go the full cycle, be put on hold and follow the unlikely reopen process.

I see that behavior as a contradiction to "Be nice and patient", and from comments I've read about Quora community on other social sites, this is as much an issue (or even more of an issue) as language for newbies.

Could we explicitly state in Code of Conduct that closing or downvoting a question that could be improved from a newbie is *NOT* **being nice and patient**. If explicitly stated it could moderate some over-enthusiastic censors.

Comment: Users who vote to close != "censors". I think you have the wrong idea about what censure actually is.

Comment: Closing and voting are quality control, they can’t be “unkind” or “unwelcoming”, or whatever other adjective someone unfamiliar with the system might assign to it

Comment: Could we explicitly state in the code of conduct that we don't vote on users or potential, but on posts in their current state, and that for appropriate moderation, the mantra _vote early, vote often_ still goes?

Comment: This is pretty much the reason why the CoC change was so controversial.  SO users have an inkling what is going to happen  next.  It has to be done slowly, they first have to chase away a lot of people and that takes time.  Give it two years or so.

Comment: It would be cool to vote on questions, not on users... but with the Gaming System It's hard not to vote on users. Over time I've found that because of this it's much harder to ask questions on Stack Overflow that providing answers. You provide answer when you know about a subject and high quality content is easy... asking question is about when you don't know. Downvotes and close can often be felt as a rejection of asker because he don't know (hey, that's why he asked ? Isn't it ? Why should he ask if he knew ?)

Comment: I'll agree with you in one point: **the whole CoC thing tries to regulate how we communicate, but the main problem with some users perceiving the site as _hostile_ has more to do with its intrinsic quality control mechanics than with actual rudeness** (although that does exist as well). But the new kindness initiative won’t help make the site to be perceived as more welcoming because what these users object are the basic tools we use to moderate and curate the site.

Comment: I am a close vote and I find this offensive. :(

Comment: Usually, the CoC violation happens before the fast close.  Using SO volunteers to look up answers that could be easily found from Google, easily available documentation, a newbie textbook or a 'Computers 101' tutorial site is massively unwelcome.  SO contributors are continually being misused as a lookup service, a free drone army to do the mundane ditch-digging of diligent research - how welcoming is that?

Comment: @MartinJames: Very welcoming or extremely unwelcoming, depending on your perspective. And that perspective is the whole problem with this "welcoming" debate.

Comment: @Cerbrus I wish I could disagree with you.  The CoC etc. is working too - I, for one, just can't be bothered with handling the garbage any more.  May as well just forget it, let the cucumbers add to their 500k rep and allow the deadbeats to get their mega-dupe homework answers:(

Comment: @Martin James: fully I agree with you, most of the garbage questions closed are indeed garbage. The trouble is with 1 percent (or probably less) remaining, which is also closed. And there is no mechanism enabling to pull attention to that and say "hey, that one may not be garbage". The reopen system is wayyy too heavy for that.

Comment: Could we actually make it clear in the CoC that closing and downvoting questions is **not not** being nice and patient? That being said, I agree that reopening questions should not be that hard, maybe reopening mjolnired questions could take only three reopen votes or something.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: we could write words to make it clear all we want that closing and downvoting are nice... but it would still be actually not being nice for new users and leading them away from Stack Overflow. We can accept that the curing system used is harsh and go along with it, because even if the potion is bitter the illness is worse. That still does not make it user friendly or nice to newcomers. Ask people rejected from Stack Overflow hanging around on other sites if you mind. Stack Overflow people are "horrible and rude" and CoC is not the main culprit.

Comment: It really depends how you see 'welcoming' and nice, @kriss. You seem to see it as accepting to keep questions opened while they get reworked, others (me included) don't see a problem with closing the question, then engaging with the user nicely, politely and patiently, to get the question in a better shape, if possible

Comment: 'Ask people rejected from Stack Overflow hanging around on other sites' - why?  They were rejected from Stack Overflow, presumably for persistently asking bad questions or behaving in an some other unaceptable manner. If they wish to lash out on external sites, there isn't much we can do about it, save just giving in to those who would abuse us:(

Comment: And we will never give in _[gladiator-like music plays crescendo in the background]_

Comment: These "Stack Overflow rejects" represent a group of people who either treated SO as a personal helpdesk or did not follow our code of conduct (since following the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines are part of the CoC). No user, new or not, is entitled to having all their questions answered here. Calling our community "horrible and rude" after contributing negatively to a repository of high quality questions and answers is, at the very least, nonsensical and disrespectful to what we're doing here (for free, even).

Comment: @yivi Could you name a single essential difference between a censor and an avid VtC voter? Well, I can: a censor "closes" only the not enough system-conform content, while the avid VtC voters close practically everything.

Comment: @peterh 'censor' is a position that is salaried.

Comment: @MartinJames This difference roots in the non-profit financial mechanism of the SE, and not in the content filtering mechanisms. I think the only essential difference is that our most avid VtC voters are clicking close in more than 90% of the cases, while real censors are filtering only the non system-conformant content. I could collect some particularly terrible examples with the SEDE, however the users I name are considering it typically as a personal insult, instead of being pride, how well are they cleaning up the site.

Comment: @E_net4 My network-wide rep is 39K, and I have still troubles if I need to ask a question. No, I don't believe that it is my problem. I believe, the quality control is a mix between some avid VtC voters voting to close practically everything what they can. They would likely empty the site soon, if they could - I could name some other SE sites where they got the full control, and include their stats beside. Believe me, it would be really convincing. There is is also a little group of voters working on the other side. The survival of a questions depend mainly on luck...

Comment: @E_net4 If a low-rep user would say these, but I am here since 4 years and I am nearing 40k network-wide (+ I am one of the most active editors & voters network-wide). And I have still problems if I ask a question, *I have fear before I ask a question*, while I've learned and I am actively using all the tips & tricks which could help a question to survive. May I ask you, how is it possible? And, furthermore. The most actice VtC voters have typically no, or only a very little questions. How is it possible? Maybe it is because they know the best, what can they expect?

Comment: ' most avid VtC voters are clicking close in more than 90% of the cases' well, I would not disagree that, on some says, (weekends, mostly), 90% of questions should be closed.   It would be even better if those 90% got closed before some 500k cucumber answered  them, but that's another issue.  I do diasgree with the tags 'censor' and 'avid VtC voters'.  I prefer 'curators' or 'user-moderators'.

Comment: @peterh The other SE sites do not have even one tenth of the traffic observed in Stack Overflow. How they define quality is also on their side, and we do not have to follow by some lesser example (because they are not Stack Overflow). Claiming that we want the site wiped clean is an unnecessary exaggeration as well.

Comment: Can we please stop fast-tracking deletion of harmless Meta questions? This one is one vote away from both reopening and deletion, which feels like a clear sign something is going awry.

Comment: @E_net4 I can compare the SO to others, and I say you, the SO is one of the worst. In 2014, it was far the worst. Since then, the other sites became more antagonistic and the SO has became a little bit lesser hostile, I suspect some CM effect here, but it is still one of the worst.

Comment: @duplode It has no del votes (yet), but likely it will have. Btw, if a question is deleted, it can't be also dupe target any more... ;-)

Comment: Given that I'm still receiving the answers to my problems in SO when searching on Duck Duck Go, I'm not sure how Stack Overflow is the worst of all sites in the SE network. :/

Comment: This question's deletion was appalling. As much as you can disagree with the question, proposed reflexion or I don't know what, deleting it was a really unnecessary step. Deletion is not for things one disagrees with.

Comment: see also: [Close voters call to arms: let's make this September welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373680/839601): "timely closing of inappropriate questions is helpful to new users - both askers and answerers..."

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier if anything, it should have been deleted as a dupe.  I disagree with many aspects of this question, and some of the comments, but I don't like to see meta deletion for that alone.

Answer (score 43):

Close-voting off-topic / unsalvageable / unclear questions ***is*** helpful.

It helps in maintaining the repository of *quality* questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

This isn't unkind, unwelcoming, censorship, rudeness, harassment, impatience or whatever.
It's **quality control**.

Comment: Easy to say, @Cerbrus, you're nearly never asking questions only providing answers. Try asking some question on a subject you're not mastering and see if asking a good question is *that* easy. This promotes false (rhetorical) questions.

Comment: @kriss: __[like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931910/c-to-php-translation-decryption-function)__ I asked about 2 languages I'm not experienced in?

Comment: Its _usually_ helpful. When the close votes and such are blatantly incorrect then it isn't very helpful.

Comment: While I agree the literal meaning of your answer, I strongly disagree its unsaid postulate, which declares the quality control unerring. My opinion is that the *quality of the quality control* of the site is not better as the quality of the questions of the rep1 users, and that it is an inherent and neglected problem in the system.

Comment: @peterh what?  You are claiming that somewhere between 80 and 100% of SO moderation is bad?  I dont see where it's claimed that quality control is unerring:(

Comment: @MartinJames No. I am claiming that voting for closure in more than 90% of the VtC reviews is bad.

Comment: @MartinJames The result is that we have some avid VtC reviewers voting nearly always for close, and a minority being more lenient. What will be the fate of a question, depends mainly on luck. I think the only reason, why the SE allows is that we have simply too few VtC reviewers. In my opinion, some structural change should be applied on the system to deal with this problem. Honestly, I have 39k network-wide rep, and I still have to deal with a large fear before I ask a question. I simply can't believe that it is my fault.

Comment: @MartinJames Another funny thing is that my meta activities tend to attract main site downs, probably from users being in the first line suggesting suspension in discussions about voting irregularities.

Comment: @peterh: You're making some quite wild assumptions. I'm not suggesting the quality control mechanism always works. Even so, when it doesn't, the actions can easily be undone.

Answer (score 31):

Your issue seems to be with the word "patient". This word in that sentence does *not* mean *"Give a question asker all the time they need to provide all details necessary to answer their question"*. They had all the time in the world for that *before* asking their question.

It means that when you're discussing a question or answer in comments, you should keep your calm when they don't seem to immediately understand you.

This means we should still downvote and close-vote unclear questions that show no research effort as soon as possible, so nobody wastes their time trying to answer it as they interpret (or guess) the problem.

See also [How soon should I “vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close/98026):

> preventing other users from answering is exactly why we close questions

Comment: Do you mean don't ask a question if you don't already have the answer ? Because for me it has been a long time since I couldn't find an already existing answer using google or digging around source code. Actually, the remaining unsolved questions are very likely to be `too localised`

Comment: @kriss: No. He means _"don't ask a question if it's poorly researched or poorly written."_

Comment: I already had a discussion on meta about "preventing others from answering". I feel it as someone trying to decide for me what I should do. It is clear enough it's in no way an incentive to answer to another question on Stack Overflow. It's more like "hey: I typed hald of and answer" and some people decided to throw away the time I just spent because he doesn't see the question in the same perspective as me.

Comment: You just need to get better at identifying what questions are high quality and on topic, and thus which ones are worth spending the time on. It doesn’t mean the current process isn’t working just fine

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes "Don't ask a Question" That leads to a profile with more than 1300 answers and 7 questions. And mine of not much better. I don't believe that is a good balance. That is because it's structurally easier answering than asking.

Comment: @kriss Not sure what you're getting at. If I have nothing I want/need to ask, because I can figure out all my problems by myself, *and* I have the capacity to help others sort out their issues too by answering, then I shouldn't participate…?! ‍♂️

Comment: @kriss: I'm not saying _"Don't ask a Question"_. I'm saying a user that wants to ask a question should do ___research___ first, and make sure their question is _properly_ written. How on earth is it a bad thing that I've answered a lot of questions?

Comment: _it's structurally easier answering than asking._ Why is that relevant, though? Even if true, why should that have an effect on the speed or nature of our quality control? Surely that just means we need to keep questions under closer scrutiny, because they have greater potential to fall foul of the quality standards

Comment: @Clive: simple enough, newbies trying hard enough should be helped and welcomed not rejected. Because they are asking the real questions. Do you believe people don't improve over time and that content should have the same quality on a first post than after a few years of practise ? That implies for "quality controllers" to take it into account and be more patient or tolerant with beginners.

Comment: Again, voting is not, and cannot be, “unwelcoming”. Your premise is fundamentally flawed I’m afraid.

Comment: @kriss I understand where you're coming from, and certainly, one needs to learn the ropes of SO at first. But *not* closing is not helping. That's sacrificing the entire system for the sake of not hurting a few feelings. Arguably SO's quality control mechanisms are exactly why everyone is using SO, because it's *not* Reddit or Yahoo Answers. And if you allow sub-par questions to newbies, they *won't learn* the ropes and continue posting sub-par questions (they will probably improve over time, but probably less so than if they're forced to).

Comment: @deceze: that's not the point, if we disagree on the subject if a question should be closed or not, say I believe it should be close because it's stupid, and you believe otherwise, the current mechanism is that I will be able to start the close process voting to close and you will just have to shut up (no way to say you believe the content is ok). Of course later, there is the reopening mechanism, but given the amount of material it's very unlikely you'll still be interrested enough to come back and vote to salvage it. I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: @deceze: notice that it only applies on questions where quality control disagree, which are indeed exception. Most closed questions are really bad.

Comment: @kriss Well, to that end: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298705/476, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252010/476

Comment: @kriss: You seem to have changed your focus. Your post was about whether closing question is "unwelcoming". You've now ditched that notion entirely, and you're focusing instead on the extreme minority of questions whose closure is debatable. That has nothing to do with being "welcoming" or not.

Comment: Your citate can't be found in the current version of that meta post.

Answer (score 23):

> In the code of conduct I read: "If you're here to help others, be
>   patient, and welcoming". As I understand it, it does not just applies
>   to what we write but also to what we do: Namely voting to close a
>   question or downvoting it is not welcoming for newbies.

Your issue here is a fundamental misconception.

There's a reason a closed question shows as "on hold" for a while before actually showing as closed. There's a reason downvotes are reversible after edits. It's not actually impatient to downvote and close a question quickly, the process is then supposed to conclude with OP editing their question to be on topic, and then the downvotes may be reversed and the question reopened.

Comment: I mostly agree with you. But as I wrote the trouble is that it's impossible to say that you judge a question is already ok or nearly ok, because only votes to close are collected, not votes to keep it open. This way the only advice taken into account is from people **rejecting** a question, there is not way to **accept** a question (which of course wouldn't apply to really bad questions).

Comment: @kriss There's a way to reopen it, which completly negates the closing process. You do need enough people to agree on reopening though.

Comment: I know of that, but it's totally different than "Voting to keep open" on the original question. Also there are some sheep effect with close: as soon as somebody do it, others usually follow. That should be balanced with a "keep open" button (that may also lead to some sheep effect of it's own).

Comment: And there’s also no way to “keep closed” a crap question which is on its way to being reopened. If you have one, you have to have the other, or you’ll introduce bias to a balanced system. And your “sheep effect” obviously works both ways too. For every “sheep” jumping on the close bandwagon, there’s another one jumping on the open bandwagon.

Comment: @Clive Or more than one, as, "being welcoming" means we shouldn't close their questions.

Comment: I would be surprised if you wouldn't know that being "held" and "closed" doesn't result any difference in the system. But, if you know this, and still you gave this answer, I think you understand my down now.

Comment: @peterh huh? There's a difference: when the question is "on hold" and edited for the first time, it will be sent to reopen queue automatically. "Closed" questions don't.

Comment: Except close votes are almost NEVER reversed. In fact, it isn't even worth advising a newbie user to edit a closed question to fix it because the close voters are long gone, won't be notified when the question is edited and almost never come back and vote to reopen.  For those that work with newbies a lot, we know that the only thing to advise them is to take their fixes and post a new question.  The reopen process is not practical at all.

Answer (score 13):

> If you're here to help others, be patient, and welcoming

Cleaning up the trash (vote close/vote delete) that those that disrespect the community by unapologetically posting an unending stream of garbage. **Is helping others!**, just not *others you personally want*, and down votes are the only accepted form of feedback that is intentionally **impersonal direct way to give feedback on the *quality* of the *content* someone is providing**.

That is how the site works, if you think that is unwelcoming to you personally or offensive to you personally, that is on you, so have fun on Quora or Yahoo Answers, because when that changes here, the entire site will finish its slow crumble into dust very rapidly.

The janitor/moderators of the site have earned the right to take out the garbage to protect the relative value of the gems they have contributed to the site.

The others that post hastily incomplete and/or incoherent cries for *send me teh codez* for extremely localized or easily solved issues with a step debugger or just searching for the title of the question on Google first with `site:stackoverflow <title of crap duplicate question for the 100th time>` are **not more important** than *the others* that will not have to sift through that garbage to find the actual gems of help they are looking for.

This is a perfect example of *the needs of the many out weigh the needs of the few* and it seems you may have been one of the *few* sometime in the recent past, too bad about that, but that does not make everyone else some kind of hateful malicious troll that has spend hundreds of hours **helping others** for years, has a personal agenda out to get you in particular. *(Where you is who ever thinks they are being personally persecuted.)*

### Which is better?

Immediate feedback that your question as worded is never going to be answered very quickly. Or that you question has been answered over and over with a duplicate and you can go on with your task!

#### OR?

Your question sitting there with no answers and no comments or feedback why until the *roomba* comes along and wipes it away a few days/weeks later.

Comment: I disagree with you, because that is not what close votes are doing. When voting to close it won't stop any garbage question: the question are already there. At that stage a direct triage mechanism dispatching question between queues would be much more efficient. Some questions are duplicates, others have to be improved, many should just be deleted. It's ok and it improves content. And by the way we should probably also have a queue for outdated questions.

Comment: Voting to close is part triage (because closer picks a closing reason), but also part punishing lazy asker by keeping them from getting response (but they often already have been helped anyway, for instance showing them the question is a duplicate).  But the main effect is blocking answers. And that is pissing off answerers. This is crazy to believe people should be stupid enough to answer bad questions if left free, but won't be pissed off by the censorship and will answer some other question instead.

Comment: Also even if we want to keep some members (say newbies) from answering, setting different rep level to answer depending on the queue would be enough. And that won't stop rookies really wanting to answer a question to do it.

Comment: And also of course there is that double evaluation of question: if close if for avoiding bad questions, what are really question downvotes for ? Good questions that shouldn't be asked ? (But of course "close" helps getting helpful flag badge and downvote cost rep points). But the logical behind that double standard is really confusing.

Comment: @kriss (1) closing questions is not a preventive measure, it's a solution to the bad questions already in. There supposedly is a triage review queue, which is in dire need of improvements, but which have been deliberately put in stasis by the core development team.

Comment: @kriss (2) The whole point of closing questions is to stop it from receiving answers. Our _modus operandi_ has always been to fix the question first, and answer it after. It's actually not crazy to believe that answerers will deliberately answer bad or duplicated questions, it happens all the time. As stated above, it's much easier to answer the 100th duplicate question than closing it as a duplicate. Answerers should be looking for _good_ questions. If they choose to answer some other open, decent question, then our problem is solved!

Comment: @kriss (3) That sounds like a similar proposal to [Would it be a terrible idea to split SO up into a tiered platform?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252781/1233251), already discussed and shot down. It would have suffered from the same problems.

Comment: @kriss (4) That's a series of misconceptions, apart from the one I already said above: downvotes are a signal of quality, not only to the OP but especially to the rest of the answering community. Quality and appropriateness to the site may be correlated, but are given different curation mechanisms. Moreover, once a user has enough reputation to vote to close questions, one cannot "flag" for closure, and so no badges can be awarded from those alone (only the steward badge can be obtained from the review queues, which is not specific to closing).

Comment: @E_net: the triage queue looks like a good solution. Is it in statis because of implementation troubles ?

Comment: @E_net4: (2) at core I believe this is a newbie answering bad questions problem. I understand the risk of turning SO to a forum, which would be bad indeed. But a triage queue could solve it easily by raising the bar to answer depending on the queue. In the case of experienced SO users I believe it's counterproductive to block them answering questions because they disagree with the close patrol (if they don't disagree they won't answer). As far as I'm representative I won't ever answer another question after being shot in flight answering another which was closed. My time, not yours.

Comment: @kriss More about triage [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374881/1233251).