# Can we undelete and reopen this question that was quickly downvoted, closed and deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

New user gets his question closed and deleted VERY quickly after fixing the typo that provoked the downvotes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608908/regexp-not-working-in-javascript-runs-fine-on-regex101

OP realised the missing // but the question was <s>closed</s> deleted and answer voted down as well.

A user forgets something and then actually realise it and amends the question - but is still <s>hammer</s> **very quickly** closed and <s>hammer</s> **very quickly** deleted... I find that unfriendly.

I posted this in the hope to get the question reopened/undeleted to give someone a chance to educate the user and make the question worth keeping

Comment: Two issues are that the question does not explain what the problem is beyond "it's not working properly", and (before your recent edit) the answer explained neither how it worked nor how it addressed the underlying problem in the question.

Comment: If you want to discuss if a situation has been handled correctly, then you're not doing yourself a favor by using terms like "Kneejerk" in the title...

Comment: Low question score enables quick deletion by 20K users. It's a feature, and it's working as intended.

Comment: Typo may not have been the correct close reason, but unclear definitely was. "It's not working properly" has _never_ been a clear problem statement. I didn't get time to read your answer, but the question was _definitely_ in need of closure.

Comment: Do you just want answers like _"Yea, that was harsh" / "No that was fine"_? Or are you looking for a different discussion? What are you asking?

Comment: I am asking to review the handling. It was obviously clear to me. And the kneejerk was when there was some // missing which everybody pounced on

Comment: And now kneejerk deletion on top. Excellent

Comment: Well, when the code is _clearly to the reader_ missing something that important, and all we're told is "it's not working", then all we have to go on is that the `/`s are missing! Naturally, that's going to be the presumed problem _because there is no clear description of what is wrong._ It may have been clear to you... Or you may have thought it was, when really you had a lucky guess. There was just not nearly enough to go on to assume that the missing characters were not the problem.

Comment: The only "Kneejerk" action here is to immediately jump on Meta to complain about the closure of a low quality question. You have the tools to dispute the closure, but by going to meta, you guaranteed there would be enough critical visitors to get the question deleted.

Comment: I would have been the first to vote to close a typo question. I understood the question well and hence found it "kneejerk" from others who just blindly saw the missing /

Comment: @Cerbrus - I apologise when I believed going to meta WAS the tool to dispute a close/delete. I have voted to reopen and it was deleted

Comment: Again, you _guessed_ you understood the question well, because all you had to go on was "it's not working" and the regex, and you _guessed_ that the missing characters were not the problem. You happened to be right, but that does not make the question any more clear. I am _very good_ at regex, even if I don't answer questions on the site about it, and I would have (had I been there and had the voting privileges) closed that question as "unclear" because there's no real problem statement.

Comment: Furthermore, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Jnr.png) is unconstructive. You should know better than to complain about downvotes like that. Frankly, It may even be eligible for an _"Unfriendly or unkind"_ flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, but they annoy me no end!

Comment: I can understand that, but that doesn't make the comment acceptable.

Comment: We're supposed to be more welcoming.  Comments like that are not, at all.  Curation activities, while they seem unfriendly, are *required* to properly curate the site, and actions are taken on posts, not people.  Uncommented downvotes are not, and are **never**, "unfriendly".

Comment: So let's delete this question too then. Seems I am the only one prepared to stand up for new users

Comment: ... This question only has 1 close-vote. Far from a deletion. We all want to stand up for new users, __provided__ they put effort into their questions.

Comment: @BDL OP added that himself

Comment: @Cerbrus: `deleted by revo, Welcome to Stack Overflow, Wiktor Stribiżew 15 mins ago` Ah you mean my question.

Comment: Oh, with "this question", you're not referring to this question, but the mainsite one?

Comment: I meant "delete my question here"  - and meant it.

Comment: I edited my question here to reflect that there was not a lot of effort taken to educate OP on how to make the question worthy of answering

Comment: Any picture of the question for <10k ?

Comment: SO has devolved to a point that experts need to be felt just as unwelcome as crappy questions.  It has done nothing whatsoever to improve content.  Finding a problem with *any* question is never hard, so it can always be easily justified.  I personally fell back to mostly answering questions in a comment, gets the job done as well.  Encouraging the OP to post the answer when the question survives however doesn't work often enough.

Comment: *New* user? They've been on the site for 6 years now. They posted their first question in 2012.

Comment: Ok, 12 points made me assume they were new or at least unfamiliar

Comment: Agree completely with mplungjan.  There is a negative perception that questions and comments are too exposed to anyone with an alterior motive to -1 it, especially without providing justification.   Also greatly disagree with the statement 'Uncommented downvotes are not, and are never, "unfriendly".'.

Comment: Thanks @JimHorn - I find this whole post super unfriendly towards me and towards OP.

Comment: How are these responses to your post, in comments and answers, _"unfriendly"_? Whay should they do to be friendlier? Agree with you, and say that you are right?

Comment: We disagree with you. That doesn't make us unfriendly.

Comment: This meta question was geared towards getting the question re-opened (now undeleted) to give someone ***friendly*** to explain what was needed to NOT have it closed/deleted

Comment: Honestly, @mplungjan, right now the most unfriendly action in this whole post has been you accusing everyone else of being unfriendly. And even that... That's really not _that_ unfriendly. (Unwelcoming, and shows you really aren't here for input and discussion, but not super _unfriendly_.) If you think keeping the site up to the rules and standards as defined in the [help] is unfriendly, there's _nothing_ we're going to be able to say about this having been handled correctly that you will see as friendly.

Comment: Seriously I have in my 8.5 years here seen MANY poor questions and voted to close a LOT of them. This is not one of them - but no one in my opinion got a chance to make it worth keeping

Comment: Consider just letting it be. Even if you remain unconvinced, it's one question out of oh so many others worth looking into.

Comment: '*This is not one of them*' - I guess the community disagrees based on the fact that the question no longer exists and the responses to your question.

Comment: I have been here long enough and have enough stake in SO to keep it a quality place. In this case my experience is called into doubt and I feel that I am accused of trying to lower the quality of SO

Comment: _"no one in my opinion got a chance to make it worth keeping"_ As I stated in my answer, _the OP can still fix their question._ It can still be fixed, undeleted, and reopened, but in the state it was in? It did not meet the quality standards of the site. I've explained how in my question, and the comments under it. If the question is edited and fixed, it can be brought back.

Comment: @E_net4 I tried. I may not delete this meta question and so get more and more incentive to defend my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan wait, so you are offended that your experience is being called in to doubt but are happy to accuse people of being '*unfriendly*' when they are trying to hold up what you are being accused of lowering?

Comment: @Kendra Highly unlikely anyone dares try to reopen/fix a question so quickly closed and deleted

Comment: @Script47 Yes, I call this whole experience unfriendly towards OP and myself. I do not have a good feeling about this experience.

Comment: I voted to re-open this Meta question, but I'm not entirely hopeful of seeing anything more coming out of this. The question we speak of holds multiple issues, as already mentioned below.

Comment: I see it is closed as unclear. I have made it clearer, but I would prefer to see it deleted and will try to repress the memory of it

Comment: @E_net4 Leave it closed, I think. Even if it's "clearer" now, I think this question has officially fallen into "does not seek input and discussion."

Comment: @Kendra - that is obviously your opinion here. I tried to open a discussion but it was not to be.

Comment: @mplungjan how about the feelings of those that you called '*unfriendly*'? See, this is everything that's wrong with this '*friendly*' / *'unfriendly*' nonsense, it makes you blind to your actions and you become more worried about how people have made you feel that see the bigger picture. Take all the "feelings" out of this (so leave the facts) and what have you got left? A poor question that the community decided to close and a meta question arguing that it deserves to not be closed.

Comment: You haven't been open to any kind of input or discussion. You were only ready to state your claims, that the rest of us should accept in a friendly manner.

Comment: @mplungjan You've not honestly discussed anything, you stated your point and then continually refused to discuss ours, instead saying we're wrong and unfriendly. I've (I feel) very clearly explained what was wrong with the question on Main, and you haven't even tried to discuss those points, just instead saying it was clear enough you understood it. You haven't actually tried to counter my point with anything, while I've cited the help center. You continue to assert your postition without considering others put forward. That's not a discussion.

Comment: I'm a fairly new user, with a fairly low reputation. Imo, Votes are not friendly or unfriendly.
There is no threshold where I would consider friendly or unfriendly -3,-12 etc.
I think that you should no use "big word" or fight in front of the low reps. Just give user the time to edit and clarify the question, give reviewer and reader some time to vote and flag. The information will be in the closed panel.

Comment: @Script47 What can I say. I feel super unhappy  - how can I leave that out of this? It is a discussion of how quickly people judge a "poor" question and when someone has decided that, then the rest follows

Comment: So not only everyone is wrong but you, but all of us only "followed" someone else's reasoning, since apparenty we can't decide on our own. That's _super_ friendly.

Comment: This Meta question now looks like a duplicate of either https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/1233251 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374359/1233251 . The consensus: quick closure is _not_ misconduct.

Comment: @mplungjan: Are you saying that 4 out of 5 users that close-voted the question didn't bother to consider the question's validity? You're basically accusing them of blindly close-voting the question. That's a bold claim, and one you can't back up.

Comment: @mplungjan you see, I'm unhappy as you describing that we (the community) are all one person who simply follow the leader (so to speak). Let us not get distracted with how we "feel" and let's  focus on the merits (or lack thereof) of the question, what was good about the question? What had they provided?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes I am. There was a typo and whoever decided that it was a typo-type issue (something I am the FIRST to closevote) made the rest close and delete very quickly -  likely because the "does not work" also triggered the "poor question" issue. If you see my closevote and delete history you will see I am really quick to vote to close things that are obviously typo-type

Comment: I repeat: _"That's a bold claim, and one you can't back up."_

Comment: If you believe the other close voters voted blindly, then it behooves you to back it up.  You can't make a statement like that and not substantiate it, not if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: You *yourself* are saying [there isn't enough information](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52608908/revisions).  Come on.  This entire post seems disingenuous now.

Comment: @mplungjan I would like to point out, now that I can actually see it, _your answer_ even says "I think", as in you aren't 100% sure. But you still asserted multiple times here that the question was perfectly clear to you? The OP hasn't even commented on it or accepted it, so how do you know your answer was actually correct if the OP hasn't confirmed or denied the fact?

Comment: @mplungjan the spirit of your complaint I agree with but I don't believe anything can be done about it. You are letting the emotion cloud your actions. If I were you, I'd walk away for a while.

Comment: Now, after looking more into the answer, I'm not so sure that @mplungjan even got it right. The example in the regex tester finds **time** information. The answer shows how to get the **date** part.

Comment: There is a point to be made here about staying calm and making your point constructively. Whether you're right or wrong (and I personally believe quick closure is a good thing, so I am not really agreeing with you here), you're simply hurting your point by going down the "I'm offended and everyone is mean" route. It's not constructive, will not provide any results, and will just become a mud-slinging contest :(....

Comment: @BDL He wants to REMOVE the time info - hence my answer removed the time information

Comment: @mplungjan: And you know that from where? It's not stated in the answer nor in any comment I have seen. Or is this just a guess from your side? Edit: Forget it. You know it from the replace in the code.

Comment: @mplungjan can I enquire as to why you deleted your answer now after all ofthis?

Comment: Well, in order to know the answer, the question has to have enough information so that someone *can* answer it.  As it stands, it doesn't seem like there's enough information in order to actually do so.  There's lots of assumptions going on about what the asker wants, but there's no clear problem statement.  Just, "This isn't working." Which...doesn't give answerers enough information to latch onto.

Comment: @fbueckert: After the edits done by mplungjan, I kind of agree. The question does now contain all relevant details to answer the question. The problem statement could be a bit clearer, but even without, it is perfectly clear from the code what op wants to achieve.

Comment: @Script47 I have undeleted my answer BUT also pointed out I do not answer the question of why the regex does not work in jquery.

Comment: @mplungjan Better?  Sure.  *Answerable*?  That's debatable.  Just because there are worse questions out there doesn't make this one immune to closure, or other curation.

Comment: @fbueckert - it is a completely valid question AND a mystery to boot. I wish people would stop closing it now it is a real question with well defined expectations and a [mcve] etc.

Comment: @BDL Certainly.  I'm not so sure of that, but regex is nowhere near my forte.  I think the crux is going to come down to whether or not someone can reproduce it based on available information, and then work from there.  If they can, great.  If they can't....well, that's the point of closing, right?

Comment: @mplungjan *You* believe it to be a valid question.  Others might, and can, disagree.  I don't think the expectations are nearly as clear as you believe, but, hey, I don't know regex that well.  It could be.  That's why it's a community decision to close, and, perhaps, reopen.

Comment: @fbueckert: Since there is a StackSnipped which shows how it is not working, I guess the reproduceable part is covered.

Comment: @fbueckert The runnable code snippet built around the OP's code seems enough evidence of it being reproducible. I do think the question is in an acceptable state now, regardless of how messy the road to this point has been.

Comment: Given how quickly the jquery question is being closed, deleted, undeleted, and reopened again and again, I'm thinking that the post should probably be locked for a few hours. Unlock it again when the meta attention dies down a bit, as this constant back and forth benefits no one.

Comment: @BDL Then it should be reopened.  I think a lot of it got stuck in the weeds with the starting hostility and accusations being thrown around.

Comment: @fbueckert: Agree. And I already voted accordingly.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Could you please elaborate what you think is still missing in the question after the edits? I'd be happy to improve the question further, but I honestly don't know what is expected.

Comment: @mplungjan: Your not doing yourself or anyone else a favor by leaving those comments.

Comment: It'd be better to just lock that question for the moment; six people warring over deletion doesn't do anything constructive whatsoever.

Comment: @Script47 so I cannot win? I deleted my answer because Cerbrus questioned whether or not it answered the "why does my regex not work" - I re-opened it because you asked AND there was a reopen vote and you [accuse me of rep hoarding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374841/can-we-undelete-and-reopen-this-question-that-was-quickly-downvoted-closed-and?noredirect=1#comment634909_374841)?  And I am told off for calling people unfriendly here? wow

Comment: '*so I cannot win?*' - What is this winning you speak about? I thought there was one goal, that is to collate quality content. I am myself. I cannot speak for others and their actions. I respond to what I see. If you have a legitimate issue with a user speak to them or make another meta post without the mud slinging. *You* assumed that *we* were being '*unfriendly*' so I did some '*assuming*' of myself, not nice is it? That's why in my earlier comments, I said let's take the "feelings" out of this and look at the merits of the question (pre-edits). I was just making a clear point and it worked

Comment: @Script47 I consider having won when the question stays open, is answered by someone who knows regexes with lookbehind and why they behave weirdly in a replace. I also consider another win when people here and elsewhere, will consider twice before in a few minutes voting down and closing a question from someone regardless of membership duration who has not yet mastered the fine art of asking a question that will not summon the Kraken. I often vote to close but I also as often try to salvage a question that has merit. This one has merit imnho.

Comment: @mplungjan *'I consider having won when the question stays open'* - I'm sorry, but I *really* don't care about whether anybody wins or loses, I care about the quality of the content. Your focus once again has shifted from '*unfriendliness*' to winning / losing. At the time of you creating this post up to around the 10 minutes prior to the second deletion the original question was not worth anything. After you edited then it became somewhat usable but even then, there were still unclear parts to it.

Comment: @mplungjan Once again, I speak for myself and my actions. I have got nothing personally invested in either one of these questions and I vote based on what I see not based on who's arguing on which side. Secondly, I don't have the ability to delete vote so that takes me out of this equation. Thirdly, '*it is not working as expected.*' that is what I would class as unclear.

Comment: @mplungjan do explain how that shows what I have personally invested? Secondly, no, it shouldn't. A stranger is asking another stranger for help, the least they could do is stick around to answer queries, it goes back to my point which I made below, it should be a give and take, not a take only. You are personally invested in keeping this question open, others might be invested in keeping it closed, I frankly don't care of the outcome, merely that the outcome is reached correctly, whichever outcome that may be.

Comment: @Script47 that is horrific. I sometimes have to sleep. Many of the askers are in different timezones and have asked a question near their bedtime or when they had to drive a car or whatever. I have stayed beyond my bedtime on numerous occasions to answer any comment or answers to a question but eventually I also have to leave the keyboard for several hours. So "too bad, your question was not up to scratch, you were not around to remedy this so we closed and deleted it for you - hope you will learn from this"

Comment: @mplungjan horrific? How melodramatic do you want to be? Surely the courteous thing would be to I don't know... not post until you can give the people helping you for free your time or again, at the very least post a question that is up to scratch then feel free to disappear and come back. But this was neither up to scratch nor did the OP stick around to fix it. I praise your efforts to clean it up but you are most definitely not going to convince me that my stance that the OP should have stuck around or posted at some other time was extremely selfish on their part.

Comment: I have locked the main question for a day. Emotions from meta were spilling over to the main question and had generated several flags. Please keep the meta discussion on meta. The post will be actionable again in roughly 24 hours.

Comment: That's like saying, my car is broken and some kind person is willing to help me out on the side of the road and I say to them: '*Look here is my car, something is wrong, you fix it up for me in the meantime I'm off home as it's late and I need to get to bed. Let me know how you get on.*' - What would you say in that situation?

Comment: I say Not in anyway comparable. If a friend would sms me while I am driving telling me they did what I asked and then shout at me for not answering within what they consider a reasonable time. You are comparing apples with radiators - not even fruit to fruit

Comment: @mplungjan how can you not see the resemblance? The broken down car in my analogy is the bad question, the kind person who stops to help is the community that tried to help, and then the OP disappeared? What part doesn't match?

Comment: I.... don't think this is helpful anymore guys (Script and mplungjan). I think taking it to chat, or just walking away, would be the best thing to do at this point....

Comment: I guess, we'll have to agree to disagree. No hard feelings.

Comment: Ok. I’ll let it go

Comment: @Script47 that would depend on whether I stood a good chance of diagnosing the mechanical problem.  If so, I would reply 'fine, OK', fix the car and drive it away.  It would never be seen again.

Answer (score 22):

That question was short, so it doesn't take long to read through it. It then doesn't take long to realize that it was a question in need of closure.

Even after the missing characters were corrected, *that was an unclear question.* Period. You made an answer, because you were positive you knew what the problem was, but you very well could have been wrong. You did not have enough information to know *for sure* what the OP was looking for, and what was wrong with it.

> A user forgets something and then actually realise it and amends the question - but is still hammer closed and hammer deleted... I find that unfriendly.

First, "hammer" is a specific closing style: Gold tag-badges for duplicate closure. This was posted in a tag with plenty of eyes, and those eyes got there plenty fast. *That's the way the system was intended,* for questions to be able to be closed quickly to prevent answers. You happened to squeeze in your answer before the closure was done.

Second, there is no "hammer" deleted, not by our terms. There is *quick* deletion.

Third, *moderating the site is not unfriendly.* Moderating the site is what keeps the site clean, and keeps our quality high.

And finally, even with the missing characters added in, *this question was very unclear.* It still needed closed.

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's the unclear close reason. There was no "specific problem" in that question, just a generic "it doesn't work."

Remember that being "new" and being "low rep" are *never* excuses to break the rules. This question was not in line with our rules, our quality standards, and so it was moderated. In a high-traffic tag, that doesn't take long. But also keep in mind that *deletion is not the end for a question* if the OP bothers to make the effort to fix the post.

Comment: Noob with 12 points  - could have had 5 min to fix his question

Comment: @mplungjan: Being a "noob" is not a shield. Bad questions are *bad* regardless of who posted them.

Comment: The user's reputation is irrelevant, @mplungjan.

Comment: They had plenty of time to fix their question. For one, they had _forever_ before they posted it. New users are given a page they have to click a box to say they read before they ask their first question. After that, the help center is the familiar `?` icon in the top bar. Then, they still had time after the question was posted. And now... _they still have time._ They can still edit the question and it can still be undeleted. But they have to put in that effort themselves, we can't clarify their question for them, not with that "problem statement."

Comment: `It does not work like in regex101`. Very obvious to me why not. Too bad I was the only one seeing that

Comment: There are _many_ reasons why a regex does not work in one spot and does in another. With nothing more than "it does not work", we don't have enough to go on. As I said in comment above, I am also very good with regex, and I too would have closed that question. Perhaps not as typo, but definitely as "unclear". What about the regex was wrong? What was it matching that it shouldn't? What wasn't it that it should? There was _not enough_ to be up to our quality standards. It at the _least_ needed expected matches and actual matches.

Comment: @mplungjan: Your wrong. Most of us (at least me :)) see what ops problem might be. I just don't think that a short code and "it doesn't work" will help anyone in the future. How would anyone find the question again? How would they know if they have the same problem? And just for the records: The test data is only available in an external service. When the link target dies, or is altered, the question will be completely impossible to solve.

Comment: And it wasn't a noob. The user account will be 6 years old in a few weeks time. Not that that matters all that much.

Comment: Being able to guess what they want is always great, @mplungjan, but it does not excuse _anyone_ from our quality standards. From Jon Skeet himself to the newest Joe Person that just picked up his first language, everyone is expected to follow the same standards, and this post did not adhere to those.

Answer (score 13):

Not only are questions asking about errors due to typographical errors a - generally speaking - good way to detect low effort questions, but they're also not worth being kept around as they hold no value to future readers (except a "Don't post stuff like that).

Adding to that was the way the question was asked, unclear at the very least. Questions like that should not be answered imo.

As a side note: If you find yourself starting your answer with "I think this is what you're looking for", *the question might be unclear*.

Comment: There was no typographical error, it was a mistake when OP pasted the code as seen in the comments

Comment: Had it been a typo type, I would have been the first to vote to close as typo

Comment: @mplungjan If I were to include the possibility of change into the process of assessing content, I'd never vote/flag anything. I vote on what I see, not what can be. The OP can now edit the question, and ask for un-deletion.